# Concate string into temp table in cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, concatenation, temp-tables

I have a temp table structure `@temp2` like this

```
route   total    driverID
------------------------
10B      300    
7B       400
```

and would like to add the `driverID` column with a result like `5555, 68989`

to do this, I use the cursor to loop another table look like this

```
driverID    routeNo
-------------------
5555        10B
68989       10B
72000       7B
```

Here is the code

```
declare @driverID varchar(max)
declare @routeNew varchar(20)



DECLARE brand_cursor CURSOR FOR     

        select distinct driver_id, route_number from [dbcwl].[dbo].[collection_deduction_summary] 
        where YEAR(trans_date) =  @year
        and MONTH(trans_date) = @month
        and route_number in (select actual_route from [dbcwl].[dbo].[livedispatchingdata_pmhs_daily_summary] where status = 'OK' and YEAR(trans_date) = @year AND month(trans_date) = @month )
        and vehicle_id in (select vehicle_id from [dbcwl].[dbo].[livedispatchingdata_pmhs_daily_summary] where status = 'OK' and YEAR(trans_date) = @year AND month(trans_date) = @month  )
        group by route_number, driver_id
        OPEN brand_cursor    

FETCH NEXT FROM brand_cursor     
INTO @driverID, @routeNew

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
BEGIN    
        --update @temp2
        update @temp2 set driverID +=  ','+ @driverID where routeNo = @routeNew; 

        FETCH NEXT FROM brand_cursor     
    INTO @driverID, @routeNew

    END     
    CLOSE brand_cursor;    
    DEALLOCATE brand_cursor;
```

sadly, I got the `driverID` column is null

and would like to have finalized temp table look like this:

```
 route   total    driverID
    ------------------------
    10B      300    5555,68989
    7B       400    72000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with cte as -- Step 1: Get all Driver Ids by routeNo
(
  SELECT routeNo, driverID = 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(driverID AS NVARCHAR(100))
           FROM #A b 
           WHERE b.routeNo = a.routeNo 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM #A a
GROUP BY routeNo
)
update b -- Step 2: Update driverID accordingly.
set driverID = cte.driverID
from #B b
inner join cte on b.route = cte.routeNo
```

[**Result here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f72a9841a9165a2232593e216f27fea)

[image]

Comment: do you mind if i can also get the total driverID per route? @phong

Comment: Is this one? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fdc1637298892fb56e7fd004469a5a58

Answer (score 1):

You can `string_agg()`:

```
update t
    set t.driverID = ot.drivers
    from @temp2 t join
         (select ot.routeNo, string_agg(driverID, ',') as drivers
          from othertable ot
          group by ot.routeNo
         ) ot
         on t.routeNo = ot.routeNo;
```